# Exclude various nodes from an XML export

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have imported an XML into excel and would like to export the XML from excel, but exclude some nodes that have been mapped.
Here is the XML currently:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<ImportExportRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>1.99</Version>
    <Product>Test Software</Product>
   -<Employees>
      -<Employee>
          <EmployeeID>76</EmployeeID>
          <Name>John Smith</Name>
       </Employee>
    <Employees>
   -<Job Roles>
      -<Role>
         -<Individual>
              <Skillset>55</Skillset>
              <Skillset2>854</Skillset2>
          </Individual>
       </Role>
    </Job Roles>
   -<Attributes>
      -<Att1>
         -<Related>
              <DataInput>98545</DataInput>
              <DataOutput>874445</DataOutput>
          </Related>
       </Att1>
    </Attributes>
```

And I would like it to export

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<ImportExportRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>1.99</Version>
    <Product>Test Software</Product>
   -<Employees>
      -<Employee>
          <EmployeeID>76</EmployeeID>
          <Name>John Smith</Name>
       </Employee>
    <Employees>
   -<Job Roles>
      -<Role>
         -<Individual>
              <Skillset>55</Skillset>
          </Individual>
       </Role>
    </Job Roles>
```

The code I am using to export the XML currently is this:

```vb
Sub ExportAsXMLData()
 Dim objMapToExport As XmlMap

 Set objMapToExport = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("ALL")

 If objMapToExport.IsExportable Then

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData "Employee Data.xml", objMapToExport
 Else
 MsgBox "Cannot use " & objMapToExport.Name & _
 "to export the contents of the worksheet to XML data."
 End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Delete the nodes from the document.

Answer (score 1):

Use MSXML2.DOMDocument object to parse the document and then you can manipulate the nodes with the available methods.

Try something like this :

```
Dim xmlObj As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlSelector As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection

Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

With xmlObj
  .validateOnParse = true
  .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  If Not .load(xmlDocPath) Then
    (throw error...)
  End If
  Set xmlSelector = xmlObj.selectNodes("/ImportExportRecord/Attributes") 'take xpath as argument'
  xmlSelector.removeAll
  .save(saveToFilePath) 
End With
```

You need to check that "Microsoft XML, v3.0" library is checked in your referenced libraries.

Comment: That throws out a Syntax error here:  If Not .load(xmlDocPath)
    (throw error...), apologies I am not an expert at this. What available methods will this give me?

Comment: You need to replace xmlDocPath with the path to your XML document

Comment: Tried this:  If Not .load("C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\1.xml") and still getting a syntax error

Comment: Because "Then" keyword is missing

Comment: Sorry, now there's a syntax error on (throw error...)

Comment: I've removed the line and now I'm getting run-time error '91'

Comment: My bad, i forgot to initialize XML object. I added the line to my answer.

Comment: Okay no errors now, but what is that supposed to have done? Exported another xml somewhere? What do I do now? Sorry for my lack of coding knowledge!

Comment: Noprob, you are welcomed. Now the xmlObj is supposed to have its "attributes" tag deleted for this example. But my code do not save any file so you cant see it. Try add .save("C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\filename.xml") within your code (i updated my answer again) and see if the file is created and without the deleted tags.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If I also wanted to omit say "<Job Roles>", how would I add that into selectNodes("/ImportExportRecord/Attributes").

Comment: same logic. Just add those 2 lines before the save. "Set xmlSelector = .selectNodes("/ImportExportRecord/Job Roles") xmlSelector .removeAll".  But beware because XML tags are not supposed to have spaces so it might result into errors.